# "Pain to" vs. "pain in"

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Is it correct to say:

> He couldn't stand for long because of pain to his leg.

or should it be:

> He couldn't stand for long because of pain in his leg.

or are both acceptable, or is neither?

Comment: In this context, "pain in" would be preferred.

Comment: "...the pain to" is acceptable, if a little old-fashioned.

Comment: "pain in" sounds like an inner pain that comes from strain/soreness etc. where as "pain to" sounds like an external force delivering the pain. e,g. of pain to: A mace smashed the knight's armor with shocking pain to his body.

Answer (score 2):

**to** would imply an external force exerting the feeling.

**in** would imply *the leg itself* is creating the feeling.

"Pain" is a bit uncommon when combined with "to", but examples can be had:

> The impact of the baseball bat sent excruciating pain **to** his leg.

"Pressure" works easily in both cases, and may illustrate the difference:

> He couldn't stand for long because of pressure **to** his leg.

A [compression sock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_stockings) is *applying* external pressure to his leg, so he cannot stand.

> He couldn't stand for long because of pressure **in** his leg.

The muscles and skeleton of his leg *feel* as if pressure is being applied due to swelling, but no "external" pressure is actually being applied.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

> He couldn't stand for long because of pain in his leg.

You can see a detailed article about uses of "in" at : [Talk english](http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/prepositions-on-at-in.aspx)

Comment: Why isn't 'the pain to his leg' allowable?

Comment: Well, to me, it suggests that the pain travels to the leg, rather than from the leg to the brain.

Comment: A link to a generic page about a few of the most common (and versatile) prepositions in English is really not useful in cases like this.